# Reassign param type - typescript

Tags: typescript

```
type T0 = {
  a: string
  b: string
}
type T1 = Omit<T0, 'b'>
function func({ param }: { param: T0 | T1 }) {
    if (param.hasOwnProperty('b')) { /* reassign type */ }
  return param.b
}
```

Is there a possibility to reassign type for `param` from `T0 | T1` to `T0`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should just put optional b and use just one type

```
type T0 = {a:string, b:?string }
```